# Setting Up Uberjar with Nginx on Digital Ocean VPS

Tags: nginx, clojure, proxy, vps, uberjar

I used the instructions on the following link:

["Hosting Clojure Web Apps in 7 Easy Steps"](http://side-effects-bang.blogspot.com/2014/12/hosting-clojure-web-apps-in-7-easy-steps.html)

I know the uberjar works because i tested it both on my dev machine and the VPS.

It's just that Nginx doesn't seem to be able to find it.
I suspect that it has something to do with this site code:

```
# Web sockets
location /chsk {
proxy_pass http://backend/chsk;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

...but I don't know how to correct it...thanks for the help!

One other thing: on the "upstream backend" in the site file i tried both 127.0.0.1:3000 AND 0.0.0.0:3000 with no success.

Here's the default site config:

```
server {
# Replace this port with the right one for your requirements
listen [::]:80 ipv6only=off;

# Multiple hostnames separated by spaces.  Replace these as well.
server_name clmitchell.net www.clmitchell.net main.clmitchell.net
books.clmitchell.net dna.clmitchell.net help.clmitchell.net
history.clmitchell.net svcs.clmitchell.net;
server_name_in_redirect off;

root /data/nginx/www/$host;

error_page 401 /error/401.shtml;
error_page 402 /error/402.shtml;
error_page 403 /error/403.shtml;
error_page 404 /error/404.shtml;
error_page 500 501 502 503 504 /error/500.shtml;

location ^~ /error/ {
  internal;
  root /data/nginx/www/www.clmitchell.net;
}


access_log /var/log/nginx/$host-access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;
# Support Clean (aka Search Engine Friendly) URLs
location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

# serve static files directly
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico)$ {
  access_log off;
  expires max;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ \.scm$ {
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
  # By all means use a different server for the fcgi processes if you need to
  fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9981;
}

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
  }
}
```

I removed history.clmitchell.net from the list of server names.

Here's the current history site config:

```
upstream backend {
   server 104.131.29.212:3000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server{
  listen [::]:80 ipv6only=off;
  server_name localhost history.clmitchell.net;

  access_log /var/log/hist_access.log;
  error_log /var/log/hist_error.log;

  root /var//resources/public;

  # Web sockets
  location /chsk {
    proxy_pass http://backend/chsk;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }

  # Static assets
  location / {
    try_files $uri @backend;
  }

  # The backend server
  location @backend {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

there was a duplicate "listen" directive on the history site config, which i removed...but for some reason I'm still getting the error: '

> sudo nginx -t
>   nginx: [emerg] duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/hist:6
>   nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: A link to the tutorial behind your configuration is dead. Fix that, please.

Comment: No it isn't...I was just on it and tested the link in my question.

Comment: Then I wonder what `http://%22Hosting%20Cllojure%20Web%20Apps%20in%207%20Easy%20Steps%22` is supposed to mean.

Comment: You were right; Sorry! The URL has been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
proxy_pass http://backend;
```

And make sure you can access http://127.0.0.1:3000/chsk if your upstream is defined as below

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}
```

Or if we has only one backend server we can just use proxy_pass  without upstream backend defined. e.g.

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; I've added more detail...please review and advise.

Comment: Please show me your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf . I think there is duplicate listen options in it.

Answer (score 0):

I learned a new lesson today: no two sites on a Nginx web server can have the same listen port!
I moved the new site to a new port and updated all the links...PROBLEM SOLVED!

Comment: It 's not true!  This example is OK :  `   server {
        listen       8082;
        server_name  domainA;
   }

   server {
        listen       8082;
        server_name  domainB;
   }` But if we have the same server_name and the same port it will fail.